# PowerBi Error. We're unable to connect. Please delete your credentials and try again later

Tags: internet-explorer, oauth, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

The following error appears whenever I try to connect to the data sources and authenticate using oAuth login screen on iExplorer web browser.

[image: Error screenshot 01]

[image: Error screenshot 02]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A new Power BI option enables the possibility to use your default browser to load the oAuth page.

File -> Options and settings -> Options -> Global -> Security -> Authentication Browser -> Use my default web browser (check this box)

[image: Unable to connect solution]

If the authentication window for Power BI (or data connector) can't open for some reason, this option allows you to use your default web browser to authenticate instead.

Note: Please, update Power BI Desktop to a recent version to get this option.

Comment: File -> Options and settings -> Options -> Global -> Security ->  Authentication Browser -> Use my default web browser (check this box)

Comment: Note: Please, update Power BI Desktop to a recent version to get this option.

Comment: Note that this is a recent bug from PowerBI and Microsoft is [investigating it](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/We-re-unable-to-connect-please-delete-your-credentials-and-try/m-p/2558140#M904993). In the mean time, you can use the suggested [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72702112/6908282)